# Rutherford Model of Atomic nucleus

Tags: electromagnetism, atomic-physics

I was studying the Rutherford Model of Atomic Nucleus. One of its drawbacks was it ignored the fact that electrons in circular motion are constantly radiating energy and will eventually collide with the nucleus in a spiral path. A question came to my mind, Can we derive an expression for the time taken by the electron to collide into the nucleus or it can't be measured?

Comment: The time to collide cannot be measured simply because it does not happen in reality.  As such a calculation isn't much practical use.

Comment: Those answers say a lot, but it's hard to find an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/em/el5.pdf

Page 133 gives an estimate based on dipole radiation.

Comment: Link dependant answers are very strongly discouraged.  I'd suggest entering teh relevant equation(s) using [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  Links can (and do) go dead and the answer will otherwise be useless.  If the reference is a book or paper, it also helps to give that too.